# Beginner conditional probablity calculation

Tags: probability

You're selling a production machine P and offer both a maintenance contract as well as an insurance against possible failure.

You know that 45% of customers do not arrange a maintenance contract and 65% do not arrange an insurance.
25% do neither.

---

a) Whats the probablity of a customer, who didn't arrange an insurance, also not arranging a maintenance contract? (Solution: 38,46%)

b) Whats the probablity of a customer arranging both? (Solution: 15%)

c) Whats the probablity of a customer, who did arrange a maintenance contract, also arranging an insurance? (Solution 27.27%)

---

I have no idea how to arrive at these solutions.

On the first question: With "$M$ = No Maintance" and "$I$ = No Insurance" i thought about $$P(M|I)=\frac{0.45}{0.75 *0.65}$$ but that doesnt work.

Comment: $\Pr(M|I)=\frac{\Pr(M\cap I)}{\Pr(I)}$ by definition.  This doesn't seem to have any relation to what you wrote down.  We are given $\Pr(I)=.65$  What is $\Pr(M \cap I)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question:

$P(M \cap I)=0.25$ so you can find the probability $P(M|I)$

For the second question:

You need to find $P(M^c \cap I^c)$

Note that $$P(M^c \cap I^c)=1-P(M \cup I)=1-[P(M)+P(I)-P(M \cap I)]$$

For the third question:

You need to find $$P(I^c|M^c)=\frac{P(M^c \cap I^c)}{P(M^c)}$$

which can be found using the result of the second question.